# Responsive Classic webpart page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, pages, responsive

I have created a new homepage on Sharepoint Online which has Carousel, List Webpart, Calendar and script editor web parts(It is on Classic Experience). When I view it in mobile, it renders whole page in mobile browser and we have to zoom in to view items in list and calendars etc, but when I click on Lists title it redirects me to lists and they are responsive means I can view and scroll and event navigation links are stacked. How can i achieve this on that homepage too.

Please guide.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to apply the [PNP Responsive](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive) solution. This uses client side functionality to make classic pages responsive. This does help with nav, as well as OOB library and list web parts. You'll probably need to make adjustments for 3rd party web parts, the carousel, etc.